# I am having issue with Mozilla Firefox and background image

Tags: css, image, firefox, background-image

I am working on a website an I set background image on webpage. I checked this page on different browser and its working good in Chrome, Chrome Canary and IE 9 but not with Fire fox. Here are my CSS codes

```
container{
    height:80vh;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;    
    color:white;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

container::before {
    height:80vh;
    width:100%;
    content : "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('/imgs/backG.jpg');

}

material{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:90%;
}

infobox{
    width:48%;
    height:70%;
    float:right;
    line-height:1.5em;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;    
}

titlenote{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size:1.875em;
    color:#e74c3c;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
}   

description{
    font-size:1.2em;
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family: Armata;
    line-height:1.5em;
    color:white;
}
signup{
    text-align:center;
    width:45%;
    height:70%;
    float:left;
    line-height:1.5em;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

and here are my images from firefox and chrome browsers,
1) [firefox] (http://postimg.org/image/k6b50g2pv/) image
2) [chrome] (http://postimg.org/image/ic7ha6ugz/) image

It is also messed up with font size and all. I am learning CSS and everything so I don't know how to fix this. I tried a lot to google solution but couldn't find it. Please help me if anyone can.

```
<container>
    <material>
        <signup><h1>Join today </h1>
        <form id="signup" autocomplete="off">
            "all input tags are here"
        </form>
    </signup>
    <infobox>
        <titlenote>Welcome to website</titlenote>
            <description>Lorem ispun stuff</description>
        </infobox>
    </material>
</container>
```

And here is jsfiddle link for demo. jsfiddle/pccnfv4f/ and I cant put more then two links so.

Comment: Post your html too, stackoverflow has a js + css + html preview now fyi.

Comment: Please upload your code on JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the positioning of your pseudo-element `container::before`.

You specify that you want i tobe absolutely positioned in relation to it's parent, and that's fine. All the browsers assume that you want it positioned in the top left corner, but Firefox doesn't. So all you need to do is make that absolutely clear:

```
container:before {
    top: 0;   <- Add these
    left: 0;  <- two lines
    height:80vh;
    ...
```

...and you're good to go!